# Term for inability to relate to struggle due to privelege?

Tags: terminology

Is there a word or term that identifies the inability of those who have lived a privileged life to relate or understand those who have had to struggle to get where they are?

Comment: One possibility is [empathy gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empathy_gap) - see for example: https://www.psychologytoday.com/ca/blog/listen/201410/how-teachers-can-reduce-the-empathy-gap-wealth-creates

Comment: However, note that [Ruttan, McDonnell, & Nordgren (2015)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1037/pspi0000012) suggest that this doesn't actually happen - in reality, the level of empathy of those who better relate is lower.